# Multiple inline assignments in one statement in c#

Tags: c#, variable-assignment

Obviously the following is totally fine in c#;

```
int a;
int b = a = 2;
```

Is it possible to do multiple variable assignments in c# in a single statement?

i.e. something like;

```
int a = (int b = 2);
```

Comment: Why would you torture that poor innocent inoffensive bit of syntax?

Comment: @MarcGravell Because think of the cycles we could save. We'll be rich!

Comment: @maxp -Consider future maintainers. Don't neglect readability in your code.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey The question was purely for academic reasons! The thought crossed my mind when I read some similar code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we look at:

```
int a;
int b = a = 2;
```

That is essentially `a=2;` then `b=a;` (but without an extra eval). So we can get similar by reversing the order:

```
int a = 2, b = a;
```

However: I would say take this a bit hesitantly: please also prioritise readability.

Answer (score 3):

Not as far as I know. The only variation I know of is:

```
int a = 2, b = 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably as close as you're going to get.

```
int a, b = a = 2;

Console.WriteLine(a.ToString()); // 2
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString()); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

No but you can do

```
int a = 2, b = a;
```

Here a will be initialized and then b will be initialized with value same of a.

or

```
int a, b = 2;
```

or

```
int a = 2, b = 2;
```

or as you said

```
int a = b = 2;
```

Comment: I think `int a, b = 2;` will only initialize b and leave a uninitialized, or am I wrong?

Comment: @CarstenSchütte: being a value type a will get 0.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
int a = 2, b = 2;
```

Works fine