# How to convert Urdu string back to decimal?

Tags: c#

**How to convert urdu string back to decimal in C#.**

```
public string urduNumber = "";
public string EnglishNumberToUrduNumber(decimal number)
{   
    string str = Convert.ToString(number);
    var output = ""; // or use StringBuilder
    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        output = str.Replace("0", "٠").Replace("1", "١").Replace("2", "٢").Replace("2", "٢")
            .Replace("3", "٣").Replace("4", "۴").Replace("5", "۵")
            .Replace("6", "۶").Replace("7", "٧").Replace("8", "٨").Replace("9", "٩");
    }
    return urduNumber = output;
}
```

**Global Variables**

```
public decimal amount = 0;**
public string urdu_amount = "";
```

I tried using this but I get input exception error.

```
urdu.EnglishNumberToUrduNumber(number);
urdu_amount = urdu.urduNumber;
amount = Convert.ToDecimal(urdu_amount);
```

**This gives me this error:**
System.FormatException.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k6z9cdw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why on earth are you using a loop? The `Replace()` function will replace _every_ occurrence in your string.

Comment: that's what i want, but that's not the question.

Comment: get rid of the loop.  Also your return value is an assignment? That doesn't make any sense and definitely won't compile.

Comment: @Jonesopolis this is your code, you provided me this yesterday, but it did not had return value in it, it do compile and it does work.

Comment: please explain why return urduNumber = output is wrong?

Comment: @Jonesopolis : It compiles alright. He's performing what's called [_inline assignment_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040863/multiple-inline-assignments-in-one-statement-in-c-sharp).

Comment: @VisualVincent you are totally right, forget I said such things.

Comment: Dear guys, i do not want to convert urdu back to english, i want to use convert urdu back to decimal because i have to pass this value into a variable that is decimal, if this isn't possible then i have to change my entire code which is performing calculations on `decimal amount = 0;`

 `amount = urdu_amount;`

I think I understood, that urdu is a symbol and it cannot be converted back to decimal.

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToDecimal()` will not be able to convert the Urdu symbols to decimal, create a method to convert Urdu number back to English number:

```
public decimal UrduNumberToEnglishNumber(string urduNumber)
{
    var output = urduNumber.Replace("٠", "0").Replace( "١", "1").Replace("٢", "2").Replace( "٢", "2")
     .Replace("٣", "3").Replace("۴", "4").Replace("۵", "5").Replace("۶", "6").Replace("٧", "7").Replace("٨", "8").Replace("٩", "9");

    var result = Convert.ToDecimal(output);
    return result;
}
```